# Decompress Stream to String using SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I'd like to compress a string using SevenZipSharp and have cobbled together a C# console application (I'm new to C#) using the following code, (bits and pieces of which came from similar questions here on SO).

The compress part seems to work (albeit I'm passing in a file instead of a string), output of the compressed string to the console looks like gibberish but I'm stuck on the decompress...

I'm trying to do the same thing as here *(I think)*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4305399/3451115
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861659/3451115
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331690/3451115

Appreciate any help, ideally the console will display the compressed string followed by the decompressed string.

Thanks :)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SevenZip;

namespace _7ZipWrapper
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Temp\7za64.dll");
            SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
            compressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Ppmd;
            compressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Ultra;
            compressor.ScanOnlyWritable = true;

            var compStream = new MemoryStream();
            var decompStream = new MemoryStream();
            compressor.CompressFiles(compStream, @"C:\Temp\a.txt");

            StreamReader readerC = new StreamReader(compStream);
            Console.WriteLine(readerC.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadKey();

            // works up to here... below here output to consol is: ""
            SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(compStream);
            extractor.ExtractFile(0, decompStream);

            StreamReader readerD = new StreamReader(decompStream);
            Console.WriteLine(readerD.ReadToEnd());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of compression is binary data - it *isn't* a string. If you try to read it as a string, you'll just see garbage. That's to be expected - you shouldn't be treating it as a string.

The next problem is that you're trying to read from `compStream` twice, without "rewinding" it first. You're starting from the end of the stream, which means there's no data for it to decompress. If you just add:

```
compStream.Position = 0;
```

before you create the extractor, you may well find it works immediately. You *may* also need to rewind the `decompStream` before reading from it. So you'd have code like this:

```
 // Rewind to the start of the stream before decompressing
 compStream.Position = 0;
 SevenZipExtractor extractor = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(compStream);
 extractor.ExtractFile(0, decompStream);

 // Rewind to the start of the decompressed stream before reading
 decompStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Wonderful - this is something I would NEVER have thought to do! Thank you :-D

Comment: For what it's worth I added the first 'rewind', tested, and ended up having to add the 2nd rewind...

Comment: Follow-on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432192/why-c-sharp-error-after-refactor-the-stream-is-invalid-or-no-corresponding-si